# find cropped area of image inside the basic image with xxd

Tags: image, bmp, xxd

I done the following:
I made a screenshot of my linux desktop with gnome-screenshot then converted it to a bmp image and dumped it as raw hex values with xxd -ps.[resolution:969x1920]
From the bmp image i made before, i cropped a small area and exported it to another bmp image and dumped it as raw hex values as well with same method as before.[resolution:47x79]
Now when i go and copy a row of hex values (lets say from the end of the file just to avoid any headers) from the smaller image and try to find it on the other dumped file, it shows that there is not there.

I don't know much from image formats, i just want to know if there is something fundamental behind it that i am missing and i have to study before trying again something similar.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some example output?

Comment: sorry for being late, i can upload the two files but they are large, considering that they have hex values translated via ascii characters so we can understand them.

Comment: Maybe use significantly smaller images so that the toy problem is easier to test?